# python os module wont access my external harddrive

Tags: python, directory

So I am writing a program using the [os module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to randomly pick a file in a folder inside a folder. Here is the architecture:

```
foo_folder
    bar_folder_1
        file_1
        file_2
        ...
    ...
```

so in my code I try to get a list of all the initial folders (the ones that look like `bar_folder_1`). So I thought to use `listdir`:

```
foo_folder = "foo/bar/..." #bar is an external hard drive
contents = os.listdir(foo_folder)
```

but I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo/bar/...'
```

am I doing something incorrect? why is this happening? Is it because it is on an external hard drive (I don't understand how that could be the reason but I am out of ideas)?

Comment: What OS?  How can you have an external hard drive inside a folder?  Is it a link?  A Shortcut?

Comment: Probably a *inx OS, @jgritty.

Comment: Try `foo_folder = "foo/bar/foo_folder"`.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
foo_folder = "foo/bar"
contents = os.listdir(foo_folder)
```